# Small panel at the bottom of a QTreeWidget

Tags: qt, search, addition, qtreewidget

I'm using QT 5.4.2 and trying to create a small panel at the bottom
of a subclassed QTreeWidget.
Here is the code:

```
void HmiScenarioAutoscriptPanel::searchEmitter() {
    QWidget *child = new QWidget(ui->emitterTreeWidget);
    //QMainWindow* child = new QMainWindow;
    QLabel *labelSearch = new QLabel("Search");
    QLineEdit *lineSearch = new QLineEdit();

    lineSearch->setFixedSize(100, 20);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->emitterTreeWidget);
    layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

    layout->addWidget(child);
   layout->addWidget(labelSearch);
   layout->addWidget(lineSearch);
```

}

The label and search field correctly appear at the bottom of the tree,
however the fields overlap with the tree nodes (see image below).

Any idea why this behavior?

Ciao
Alf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjk4l.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to set layout on the tree widget. It is like other controls like a button, label etc..

I see that you are using designer. Add a blank widget (`searchWidget`) under the tree widget and then

```
void HmiScenarioAutoscriptPanel::searchEmitter() {
    QWidget *child = new QWidget(ui->searchWidget);
    //QMainWindow* child = new QMainWindow;
    QLabel *labelSearch = new QLabel("Search", searchWidget);
    QLineEdit *lineSearch = new QLineEdit(searchWidget);

    lineSearch->setFixedSize(100, 20);

    QHBoxLayout* layout = new QHBoxLayout(ui->searchWidget);
    layout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignBottom);

    layout->addWidget(child);
   layout->addWidget(labelSearch);
   layout->addWidget(lineSearch);    
}
```

---

Just out of curiosity, why don't you add these using the designer as well?

Comment: I did it with .NET and was quite successful. I was hoping with little effort, to achieve the same result in QT. However, you are probably right. Thanks anyway.